# How do I retrieve an item from database with find_by_created_at in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to query for microposts by the date they were created using the find_by_created_at method. First I found a micropost in the rails console like so:

```
1.9.3-p194 :027 > Micropost.first
```

`Micropost Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Micropost id: 409, content: "Apparently it does not like spaces either.  Check t...", user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-07-11 22:51:44", updated_at: "2013-07-11 22:51:44", receiver: "self">`

Then I copied and pasted the created_at input(minus the timestamp) into my find_by_created_at method like so:

`1.9.3-p194 :028 > Micropost.find_by_created_at("2013-07-11")`

`Micropost Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."created_at" = '2013-07-11 22:51:44' ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
 => nil`

and for some reason it comes back nil. I thought the problem might be because I did not include the time but I tried it with the timestamp also and it still came back nil.

My plan is to let a user search for and display microposts by date. Maybe something like:

`Micopost.find_by_created_at(@search_date).all`

but I am getting hung up just trying to find by created_at. Could someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Micopost.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", "2013-07-11") # Mysql/sqlite database

Micopost.where("created_at::date = ?", "2013-07-11") # PostgreSQL
```

Comment: Yes, very true. I've added that to the answer, and also PostgreSQL just in case, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Micopost.where(" created_at between ? AND ?", @search_date.beginning_of_day, @search_date.end_of_day)
```

You can also user [ryan bigg's by_star gem:](https://github.com/radar/by_star)

```
Micropost.by_day("2013-07-11")
```